# Prevent jar task from executing when only manifest changes

Tags: gradle

I am using Gradle 2.12. In my build files I configure that each module should put extra information in the manifest. I do it like this:

```
tasks.withType(Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Build-By': buildBy,
                'Build-JDK': buildJdk,
                'Build-Time-ISO-8601': buildTime_ISO_8601,
                'Build-SCM-Info': buildScmInfo
        )
    }
```

The variables are initialized once at build start.

This works fine, with one disadvantage: it causes the jar task to always be called, as it discovers its 'input' changed, and all modules depending on the jar-ed ones are recompiled, which is unnecessary. For example, with project structure:

A, B depends on A, C depends on A

When the build is executed for the second time without any code changes, A is not compiled, but a new jar is built, and for this reason B and C need to be recompiled as their dependency changed.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to move your manifest specification out of the configuration phase (by declaring it in the `doFirst` closure), to make a Gradle looking for the changes in the default manifest file, which has no changes yet. Somthing like this:

```
tasks.withType(Jar) {  
  doFirst {
     manifest {
      attributes \
        'Build-By': buildBy,
        'Build-JDK': buildJdk,
        'Build-Time-ISO-8601': buildTime_ISO_8601,
        'Build-SCM-Info': buildScmInfo
     }
  }
}
```

In that case, the Manifest content should be changed only if a jar-task will be executed.